# Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно использовать realloc

Tags: c++, valgrind

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно использовать realloc. В этом куске кода Valgrind указывает на ошибку в строке с realloc'ом:

> Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{   
    /* создаём дин. массив: 3 ряда по 4 колонки */
    int** a=(int**)malloc(3*sizeof(int*));

    for(int i=0; i<3; ++i)
    a[i]=(int*)malloc(4*sizeof(int));

    /* заполняем массив */
    for(int i=0; i<3; ++i)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<4; ++j)
        a[i][j]=i*4+j;
    }

    /* расширяем массив: 4 ряда по 5 колонок */
    a=(int**)realloc(a, 4*sizeof(int*));
   
    for(int i=0; i<4; ++i)
    a[i]=(int*)realloc(a[i], 5*sizeof(int)); // здесь Valgrind ругается
    
    /* заполняем массив другими значениями*/
    for(int i=0; i<4; ++i)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<5; ++j)
        a[i][j]=(i*5+j)+1;
    }

    /* выводим массив на экран */
    for(int i=0; i<4; ++i)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<5; ++j)
        printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
        
    /* освобождаем память */
    for(int i=0; i<4; ++i)
    free(a[i]); 

    free(a);
}
```

Comment: Как минимум, нет проверки на то, что malloc выделил память. Может, просто компилятор такой умный, что понимает это?

Comment: a=(int**)realloc(a, 4*sizeof(int*)); - подозрительное место. Вы таким образом случайно утечку памяти не делаете? Т. к. массив a ссылался на 3 участка динамической памяти. Компилятору может не нравиться, что вы в последующих реалоках даёте указатели a[i] - не очевидно, что они указывают куда нужно. Ну и, разумеется, a[3] у вас же нет, после реаллока a. Для него только malloc вызывать можно.

Comment: Память не инициализировага, вот о чем говорится в предупреждении, или ошибке, обнулить нужно память которую выделили, т к. мало ли какой адрес там будет.

Answer (score 1):

После расширения выделенной памяти

```c++
a=(int**)realloc(a, 4*sizeof(int*));
```

новые элементы `a[3]` содержат мусор памяти *(неопределённое значение указателя)*. И дальнейшая операция `realloc(a[3],...)` привёдет к неопределённому поведению *там мог быть **любой** указатель*.
Для новых элементов массива нужно выставить значение 0. `a[3]=0;`
И тогда команда `realloc(a[i],5*sizeof(int))` от значения нулевого указателя выделит вам новую память.

Answer (score 0):

- Во-первых, настоятельно рекомендую выделять одним куском память, а потом уже нарезать выделенный участок памяти, как душе угдно.
- Во-вторых, проблема в том что в выделенной памяти находятся указатели на другие выделения памяти и когда происходит реаллок, то указатели теряются и поэтому ругается valgring, поэтому если хотите использовать свой кривой способ выделения памяти, то внутренние массиво необходимо предварительно освобождать.

Ниже на основании вашего кода написал пример выделения массива как одного куска памяти. Не компилировал, могут быть опечатки, но это профессиональный способ выделения памяти - одним куском.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{   
    /* создаём дин. массив: 3 ряда по 4 колонки */
    int** a=(int**)malloc(3 * 4 * sizeof(int*));

    /* заполняем массив */
    for(int i=0; i<3; ++i)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<4; ++j)
        a[i][j]=i*4+j;
    }

    /* расширяем массив: 4 ряда по 5 колонок */
    a=(int**)realloc(a, 5 * 4 * sizeof(int*));
      
    /* заполняем массив другими значениями*/
    for(int i=0; i<4; ++i)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<5; ++j)
        a[i][j]=(i*5+j)+1;
    }

    /* выводим массив на экран */
    for(int i=0; i<4; ++i)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<5; ++j)
        printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
        
    /* освобождаем память */
    free(a);
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за объяснение! Вспомнил, что можно выделить один кусок памяти, передвигать указатель на нужные участки и записывать туда данные.